# jQuery How to fire the drag event while mouse is still down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

Ok I've been playing around with this for hours now and still no dice. I'm creating an interface allowing you to drag and drop an icon(a div with an image inside). I'm using the [jQuery UI scripts](http://jqueryui.com/) for they're tried and tested div dragging functionality.

My problem is you can not drag a div outside it's parent div. To get around this I'm creating a dragable div, appended to the document body, on demand when a user fires a mousedown event. But I can't figure out how to fire off the drag event needed so the user can immediately start dragging this newly created div around.

In short I need to; mouse down -> call function to create draggable div -> drag the div around while the mouse is still down.

I'm sure it's something simple. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of my problem, all it needs to run are the jQuery UI scripts which can be found at the link above.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <style>
    #inactive_dragable { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; background-color: green; }
    .test_drag { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; background-color: red; position: absolute; }
    </style>
    <script>

    function createDraggableDiv(e){     
        if (!e) var e = window.event;   
        jQuery('<div/>', {
            id: 'tester',
        }).appendTo('#page_wrap');      
        var isIE = document.all ? true : false;
        var _x,_y;
        if (!isIE) {
            _x = e.pageX;
            _y = e.pageY;
        }
        if (isIE) {
            _x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            _y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        var boundry = $('#page_wrap').offset();
        $('#tester').addClass('test_drag');
        $('#tester').html("New div to drag");
        $('#tester').css("top", _y + "px");
        $('#tester').css("left", _x + "px");
        $('#tester').draggable();       
        // Now how do I make the new div immediately start dragging?
        // ...
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page_wrap">
<div class="demo" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
<div onmousedown="createDraggableDiv(event);" id="inactive_dragable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click on the div I want to be able to create a new div and drag that around instantly.

Comment: Show us the code you are using to create the div.

Comment: Have added sample code, inside the createDraggableDiv function the code creates the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final edit. Here is the functionality you want. I had to modify your code a lot but this does what you want it to do. You need to pass the mousedown event you are firing into a trigger on the added div. Here is the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmSCq/21/)

This should be your html

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="page_wrap">
<div class="demo" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
<div id="inactive_dragable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your javascript

```
$(".demo").mousedown(function (e){
    var isIE = document.all ? true : false;
        var _x,_y;
        if (!isIE) {
            _x = e.pageX;
            _y = e.pageY;
        }
        if (isIE) {
            _x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            _y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        var boundry = $('#page_wrap').offset();
        $('<div/>', {
            id: 'tester',
        }).addClass('test_drag')
        .html("New div to drag")
        .css("top", _y + "px")
        .css("left", _x + "px")
        .draggable()                 
        .appendTo('#page_wrap');
        $("#tester").trigger(e); //this is the important line, that triggers the drag
});
```

And your CSS

```
#inactive_dragable { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; background-color: green; }
.test_drag { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; background-color: red; position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will put together some example code but seeing your comment I realised my app is behaving differently because I've put the draggable div inside a div with style 'overflow-y: auto;' When there is a scroll bar you can not drag it outside.

Comment: Sort of, although the mousedown is kind of a requirement, I need to be able to mousedown -> call function (which creates the div) -> while the mouse is still down drag the div around.

Comment: On mouse down append the div, presumable right where the mousedown occurred. Then without skipping a beat make that start dragging. That's going to be tricky.

Comment: I've had a play about and can't find a way to do this.  If I were you I'd get ready to think of a different approach, but keep looking in the meantime ;)

Comment: @Kyle Is it possible? I would of thought so but everything I try does not seem to work. I thought firing another mousedown event would do the trick, which I may be doing incorrectly, but no luck with that either.

Comment: @Archer Thanks, I'm thinking it might not be possible.

Comment: I think i figured it out. All you need to do is do .trigger(event). You may need to move your code around though, you need to apply all your css and whatnot on the div before you append it.

Comment: @Kyle I think I tried this, doesn't seem to fire off the draggable functions that starts dragging the div around though :/

Comment: It's because your calling the event from within your html. If you use all jquery it will work properly.

Comment: In my example code I've added the line '$("div#tester").trigger("mousedown");' underneath my comments in the JavaScript function, is this what you mean?

Comment: Oh one sec I think I understand what you mean now, no inline function calls. I'll try that.

Comment: Yeah instead of using inline event handling you can bind it using jquery. $(thingtobindto).eventname(function (eventarg){ //do stuff }). http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ it's a lot cleaner and easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: Tried it with '(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#inactive_dragable").mousedown(function(e) {...' no luck though.

Comment: You are a genius. Thankyou very much, you've solved something I wouldn't of been able to myself. I added the document.ready check before applying the handler and the positioning needs a tweak but it works perfectly thanks. I hope Google finds this as there's no quick Google solution or at least I didn't find one.

Comment: I'm no genius but I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

ok. after reading your comments i think i understand what you are trying to do, however i dont think there is a "start drag" method which we can use in jquery.

but how about this, instead of binding a mousedown event on div A which creates the new div B and then trying to drag div B, why not remove the mousedown event altogether and replace it with a draggable event, and fire off some code at the beginning of the drag event.

for example:

```
$(".selector").draggable({
  appendTo:'body',
  addClasses:'',
  scroll:false,
  start:function(){
    //your code here
    //eg:
    $(this).html('something else');
  }
});
```

the addClasses bit can change the appearance of your div, and the start event can fire off some code to alter div A (which you are now dragging) to appear like your intended div B.

EDIT: the scroll:false bit should get around the problems you are having with the "overflow:auto" parent div.

its a bit of a work around, but should give you the functionality you are after (assuming i understand you correctly this time!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've done something similar to this and it works great but then the problem is firing the drag event off manually so that as soon as the mouse is down the user can drag the div around normally.

Comment: So your mousedown to add a div event is overriding the drag event? So instead of dragging the newly added div your just adding more divs?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is going on, which is why I'm asking for help. It could be possible it's overriding the event though. With the way my app works adding the draggable div onmousedown does seem logical way to work. Please see demo code for a better explanation.

Comment: @Ally see my updated answer for some demo code that accomplishes what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: I think what he wants to do is immediately after the new div is added, and while you still have the mouse down. The new div starts dragging.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a go but it still seems to be stuck inside the container div. The only work around I can think of now is creating a custom scroll bar and not using the 'overflow' property. Seems a bit overkill though.

Comment: ok, in the start function add a bit of code to remove the "overflow:auto" css from the parent div. you can then replace this property using the `stop:function(){},` event.

Comment: there are many problems inherent with overflow:auto and draggable items. perhaps instead of using a scrollable area you use pages instead? whatever you do, dont create a scrollbar from scratch - ive done one recently and its a complete nightmare!

Comment: ignore the last two comments - the scroll:false should now solve your problems.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, where do I put the scroll false? I've tried it in the '$(".selector").draggable({...' but doesn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: `.selector` is just the identifier of what you want to drag, im guessing a html div, eg `<div class="selector">draggable</div>` - ive edited my solution and put scroll:false in the right place for you.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are better because they're discussing doing it the correct way.  However, to literally answer your question, you can trigger the mousedown event as such...

```
$("div#divID").trigger("mousedown");
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it with my sample code, still no luck. I've tried many ways similiar to this but it doesn't seem to fire off the draggable functions.

Comment: I don't expect this to work when there's a plugin involved.  It's just me being a pedant and answering the question literally, in case other people end up here looking for that specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of creating a clone which is to be dragged is already implemented in the draggable plugin. You should have used it like so:

```
$('#tester').draggable({helper: 'clone', appendTo: 'body'});
```

The appendTo option represents the element where you want the helper to be created

You can hide your initial dragged object on dragstart (or leave it there if you desire)
Here is a jsFiddle I made as a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HnpbX/6/

If you want to achieve a functionality of dragging and dropping an element from one container to another, you should use the droppable in combination with draggable