# Initialize element and start dragging with just one click

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

At `mousedown` I want to inject a new element in the DOM and start dragging it immediately (i.e. trigger `dragstart`), without clicking the new element again.

I am using d3.js a lot in my project. But I don't know if I can trigger the `dragstart` event by using d3, so I tried using jQuery:

```
$("circle#pen").trigger("dragstart");
```

But this doesn't work.

Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dcY4/), where I demonstrate my problem by trying to create a "pen" at `mousedown`, and if the user drags the pen it draws a line. At `dragend` the pen is removed and the line fades away. But the pen has to be initialized, and then it can be dragged by a new click. This is just for demonstrating the problem.

Here is a [related question for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883214/how-to-programmatically-invoke-jquery-ui-draggable-drag-start), but there are no good answer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a jQuery library called [jquery-simulate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate). By using that I solved the problem like this:

```
var coords = {  
    clientX : d3.event.x,
    clientY : d3.event.y
};

d3.select("g#selects").append("circle")
    .attr("id", "pen")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("cx", coords.clientX)
    .attr("cy", coords.clientY)
    .call(dragPen);

$("circle#pen").simulate("mousedown", coords);
```

The element `#pen` now gets injected and a drag is initiated with just one click. If you know a solution without a library like [query-simulate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate), please let me know.

Comment: @TimSeguine I agree, not a good solution. But it was what I ended up with back in 2013. What is your solution?

Comment: Based on what you described, I'd probably put the event handlers on the area where the "pen"is allowed to function. The mousedown appends the "pen" like you already did. A mousemove handler updates the "pen" position. A mouseup handler deletes the "pen". There's no real reason to insist on doing it with a drag behavior unless there's more to this than you described in your question.

Comment: @TimSeguine Ok thanks :) Well.. I don't remember exactly the use case (I don't work on that project anymore). I think the question was a simplification of the problem of how to create and start dragging an element with a single `mousedown`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there is probably more to it than that. I'm just positive there was a better way to solve the actual problem. But if it worked, that's what's most important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how jQuery's trigger method works. It is designed to trigger code that you have attached to an event. It does not trigger something to happen in the sense that a user's input would.

So to solve your problem, you need to attach some events to the element that would define the logic for moving the elements around.

Comment: Okay, but hmm.. I think I am attaching drag events to the element?! I use `d3.behavior.drag()` and call that on the element. See the fiddle for the code (it doesn't fit very good here in a comment).