# jQuery Draggable - Start dragging element by clicking on it, without holding the mouse

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Consider a basic jQuery Draggable element. Is there any method to start dragging the element with a single mouse click? (ie, when the element is clicked, it enters a drag state, and starts following the mouse, when it is clicked again, it gets dropped where it is)

If this isn't achievable with jQuery, is it achievable with any other third party dragging library?

Comment: It's not part of the default behavior. You could Widget Factory it and basically re-bind `dragstop` event to another event. What event would you want to allow the drag'd item to be released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, in a sort of hack method, by triggering the `mousedown` and `mouseup` for draggable on click event.

Reference: [How to programmatically invoke jQuery UI Draggable drag start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883214/how-to-programmatically-invoke-jquery-ui-draggable-drag-start)

Referring the answer from [fuzzyBSc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517272/fuzzybsc)

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  // Example: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events
  var $start_counter = $("#event-start"),
    $drag_counter = $("#event-drag"),
    $stop_counter = $("#event-stop"),
    counts = [0, 0, 0];

  function updateCounterStatus($event_counter, new_count) {
    // first update the status visually...
    if (!$event_counter.hasClass("ui-state-hover")) {
      $event_counter.addClass("ui-state-hover")
        .siblings().removeClass("ui-state-hover");
    }
    // ...then update the numbers
    $("span.count", $event_counter).text(new_count);
  }

  // Helper Functions
  function makeDrag(obj) {
    obj.draggable({
      start: function(e, ui) {
        counts[0]++;
        updateCounterStatus($start_counter, counts[0]);
      },
      drag: function() {
        counts[1]++;
        updateCounterStatus($drag_counter, counts[1]);
      },
      stop: function() {
        counts[2]++;
        updateCounterStatus($stop_counter, counts[2]);
      }
    });
  }

  function stopDrag(obj) {
    obj.draggable("destroy");
  }

  // Custom Click Event to trigger Drag
  $("#draggable").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("dragging")) {
      $(this).removeClass("dragging");
      e.type = "mouseup.draggable";
      e.target = this;
      $(this).trigger(e);
      stopDrag($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("dragging");
      makeDrag($(this));
      e.type = "mousedown.draggable";
      e.target = this;
      $(this).trigger(e);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 16em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

#draggable ul li {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}

* html #draggable ul li {
  height: 1%;
}

#draggable ul li span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
}

#draggable ul li span.count {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to trigger the chain of events.</p>
  <ul class="ui-helper-reset">
    <li id="event-start" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-play"></span>"start" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
    <li id="event-drag" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>"drag" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
    <li id="event-stop" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-stop"></span>"stop" invoked <span class="count">0</span>x</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, I use the Events example at https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events for the base code. I use this since it shows when events are triggered.

First, we will use `click` event to trigger start and also to trigger stop for drag. To help identify this, I add a class `dragging` so that we can determine the state of the target.

On the initial click, `dragging` not present, we will trigger the `mousedown` event for draggable within the click event. Now, without holding down the mouse button we can move the mouse and the target element will move with it. Click again to trigger the `mouseup` event for draggable.

I think this will work for most scenarios. I do not know how Mobile devices might handle this since there is not a `mousemove` type of event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this indeed answers my question, but what about if I am not able to listen neither to the click action? My intended use case for this would be mixing jQuery Draggable UI, which is a neccesity for a plugin I am using, with the native HTML 5 Drag And Drop API, to be able to drag and drop between browser windows. My plan was to create something, where I drag something between windows with the HTML 5 API, and when it fires the `dragover` event, create a draggable object with jquery, and start following the HTML 5 object.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai in a similar fashion, when you create the new object on the target window, you can trigger a new `mousedown` event with the new target. You asked X, I answered X. If you wanted know Y, you should have asked the Y question. If this answers this question, please mark it as the answer. Work on your `dragover` script and post a new question if you need more help.

Comment: I was just going through your demo once again, to try to understand it a bit more, and maybe reimplement it to my needs. Could you explain why are you destroying the original draggable after the initial click, and recreating the draggable element afterwards?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I don't have a good answer really, just basic experience. I think I was trying to avoid the click event from bubbling up to draggable. Since `click` is basically `mousedown` and `mouseup`, and those are used to trigger `dragstart`, `drag`, and `dragstop`, I just assigned a click event and then in the click event trigger the `mousedown` manually. This tricks it into following the mouse pointer as the dnd manager thinks the mouse button is pressed. The next click depresses the button and "drops" the items. I destroy the draggable so that it resets back to a waiting for click state.

Comment: I posted a followup question, with a fiddle, cause I am still having problems, maybe if you have the time, please look over it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715953/jquery-draggable-create-draggable-and-start-dragging-on-html5-native-drag-and