# Using jQuery UI's draggable, how can I drag in anywhere in the parent to move a child?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Using jQueryUI's draggable plug-in, I want to make any drag events in the parent container move a specific, single child regardless if the click and drag event started on the child  or not.

Consider this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/9rqHe/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: move;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#child').draggable();
});
```

Is it possible to delegate the draggable action on the parent to make the child move?

The `handle` option seems like it would work if it wasn't for this important caveat:

> If specified, restricts dragging from starting unless the mousedown
>   occurs on the specified element(s). **Only elements that descend from
>   the draggable element are permitted.**

Nothing else in the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) seems to point to this being possible out-of-the-box unless I'm completely missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this. but you can get a similar effect with an extra div and some jQuery and CSS.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9rqHe/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Child</div>
    <div id="ghost"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var childX = 0,
    childY = 0;
$('#ghost').draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        $('#child').offset({
            top: childY + ui.offset.top,
            left: childX + ui.offset.left
        });
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).offset({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        });
        childX = $('#child').offset().left;
        childY = $('#child').offset().top;
    }
})
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: move;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events:none;
}
#ghost {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: This definitely presents a solution to what I shared above. Obviously, my examples were dumbed down. My last hurdle is making this work with the fact that I am allowing the child element to be "zoomed" in and out (using `transform`). When I zoom in or out, it doesn't stick to the cursor as well. Any ideas on that front?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Might want to start another question with that detail added.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack I came up with on the fly since [triggering the drag event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759983/2784939) doesn't work anymore for some reason.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rqHe/3/)

Basically I put a child element into the `#child` div and use a jQuery event function to always position it over the `#parent` div.

```
function updatehack(e,ui)
{
    $('#hack').width($('#parent').width());
    $('#hack').height($('#parent').height());
    var p=$('#child').position();
    $('#hack').css('top',-p.top);
    $('#hack').css('left',-p.left);
}


$('#child').draggable({
    stop:updatehack   
});
```